# Draw lines with simplecv and pyqt4

Tags: line, pyqt4, draw, simplecv

I am trying to integrate simplecv to pyqt4 with some mixed success. I was able to see a webcam capture in pyqt4 through simplecv, I can modify the image with simplecv and it shows ok in pyqt4 but when I try to add a geometry or text to the image it is not showing in pyqt4. If I run the simpleCV code on their own it works OK. Can someone help me understand why it is not working? By the way, as you can see I am new to pyqt4 and simpleCV. See the code that I currently have.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
import signal
from PyQt4 import uic, QtGui, QtCore

from webcamGUI3 import *
from SimpleCV import *

class Webcam(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self,parent)        
        self.MainWindow = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.MainWindow.setupUi(self)
        self.webcam = Camera(0,{ "width": 640, "height": 480 })

        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()

        self.connect(self.timer, QtCore.SIGNAL('timeout()'), self.show_frame)

        self.timer.start(1);

    def show_frame(self):
        ipl_image = self.webcam.getImage()
        ipl_image.dl().circle((150, 75), 50, Color.RED, filled = True)
        data = ipl_image.getBitmap().tostring()
        image = QtGui.QImage(data, ipl_image.width, ipl_image.height, 3 * ipl_image.width, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap()
        pixmap.convertFromImage(image.rgbSwapped())
        self.MainWindow.lblWebcam.setPixmap(pixmap)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    webcam = Webcam()
    webcam.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I got my friend, is very simple you just add

ipl_image  = ipl_image.applyLayers()

see:

> ```
>     ipl_image = ipl_image = self.webcam.getImage().binarize().invert()
>     ipl_image.drawRectangle(30,50,100,100,color=Color.RED,width=3)
>     ipl_image.drawText('ola galera',80,190,fontsize=50)
>     ipl_image = ipl_image.applyLayers()
>
>
>     data = ipl_image.getBitmap().tostring()
>     image = QtGui.QImage(data, ipl_image.width, ipl_image.height, 3 * ipl_image.width, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
>     pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap()
>     pixmap.convertFromImage(image.rgbSwapped())
>     self.MainWindow.label.setPixmap(pixmap)
> ```